# ajax not importing

Tags: jquery

I'm using ajax to initially import content into a div on **about.php** and **resume.php** on the mobile site via `<body onload="ajaxLoader('http://www.frende.me/_resources/about.xml','content_right');">`. It works on the full site (www.frende.me), and on the test mobile site (test.frende.me/m/), but not on the regular mobile site (m.frende.me). I'm really perplexed because it seems like the external files to import don't exist (or there's a broken link), but I can click on the link (http://www.frende.me/_resources/about.xml) in firebug and it resolves just fine…

All I can think of is the content is being treated like it's being imported from an external site (since the page importing it is in a subdomain (m) and it's looking in the full domain (www)), and it's not being allowed, but that doesn't make sense because it works on test.frende.me/m/

EDIT: Btw, the normal mobile site (m.frende.me) is a carbon-copy of the test mobile site ( cp -R test/* . )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is working just fine m.frende.me. But, as a side note, I would avoid using Javascript on mobile sites to load content and only using Javascript on mobile sites for progressive enhancement as most phones do NOT support Javascript or only support a subset of javascript (and usually that subset doesn't include AJAX with the exception of iOS and Android).

Comment: @Jack is it working for you on [about.php](http://m.frende.me/about.php) and [resume.php](http://m.frende.me/resume.php)? the design and photo pages of the mobile site don't use ajax.

i'm using ajax so that the content can be initially loaded and then swapped. do you know of anything else that does that?

thanks

Comment: No it doesn't seem to work on about.php. It seems like your site is using Javascript just for the sake of using Javascript. If there is no reason (other than the small animation) for using Javascript, simply make each page an individual page and don't use any Javascript to load content (either load it statically or dynamically using PHP from DB, Cache, File, Etc. - NOT AJAX). If you are just using the Javascript for the animation, simply add the animation after the fact - on top of your content - this way if the Javascript fails - your content is still loaded and you are not relying on JS.

Comment: Remember basic design practices for Mobile Devices - design for the Least Common Denominator and/or make it scale. Not all phones are going to support even full HTML and CSS, let alone Javascript.

Comment: @Jack i guess i could do a php include(). i would still like to know why the ajax is not working though…. thanks again

Comment: @Jack i did consider that point, but it's _highly unlikely_ my audience is going to have a mobile device that doesn't support html/css/js, but thank you for the advice

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in <b>/home/content/48/6142848/html/m/about.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br /> 
<br />

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  include(http://www.frende.me/_resources/about.xml) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in <b>/home/content/48/6142848/html/m/about.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />

Comment: <br /> 
<b>Warning</b>:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'http://www.frende.me/_resources/about.xml' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in <b>/home/content/48/6142848/html/m/about.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />

Comment: That is what is being returned by your Javascript AJAX function. You need to allow read access to the XML file.

Comment: @Jack i noticed that too (i was just about to post it). do i just need to change the permissions on $name.xml (chmod 777 about.xml resume.xml)? or it a configuration change to the server/php?